# Bower - EPERM, unlink error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, bower, mean-stack

I'm encountering the below error stack trace, while I try to install "jQuery" using Bower. Can someone offer some help?

```
    C:\study\meanApp>bower install jquery --save
    bower not-cached    git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
    bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
    bower download      https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/2.1.1.tar.gz
    bower retry         Download of https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/2.1.1.t
    ar.gz failed, trying with git..
    bower EPERM         EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Local\Temp\AUserZ\bower\jquery-8680-AaJIqU\archive.tar.gz'

    Stack trace:
    Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Local\Temp\A-UserZ\bower\jqu
    ery-8680-AaJIqU\archive.tar.gz'

    Console trace:
    Trace
        at StandardRenderer.error (C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
    s\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:72:17)
        at Logger.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bo
    wer\bin\bower:110:22)
        at Logger.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at Logger.emit (C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\nod
    e_modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
        at C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\commands\ind
    ex.js:40:20
        at _rejected (C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_
    modules\q\q.js:797:24)
        at C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q
    .js:823:30
        at Promise.when (C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\no
    de_modules\q\q.js:1035:31)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
    de_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41)
        at C:\Users\UserZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q
    .js:557:44

    System info:
    Bower version: 1.3.9
    Node version: 0.10.18
    OS: Windows_NT 6.1.7601 ia32
```

P.S: I've gone through the StackOverflow could find nothing related to my error, hence posting this question.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 48):

Cleaning the cache resolved the error for me: `npm cache clean`

Comment: no dice on my side- I had to do what molafson suggested- npm uninstall, update, install

Comment: It works for me, but I don't understand why I have to do that. Grunt should do this automatically, is not it ?

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error "EPERM, unlink" but with a different archive.

Running these commands resolved the issue for me:

- npm uninstall -g bower
- npm update decompress-zip
- npm install -g bower

This link is where I saw to use those commands:  https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/798
It is the updating of the decompress-zip that has resolved the issue for others as well.

Comment: Hi Molafson, I tried your solution, but no luck!.. Thanks for replying!.

Answer (score 6):

I got this error and ran the bower in verbose mode. And found the error as below:

```
bower error         SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
```

To resolve this, add below line into .bowerrc created in your default home directory.

```
"strict-ssl": false
```

Try `bower install` again, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following sequence. It worked for me. 
bower cache clean
npm uninstall -g bower
npm install -g bower
bower install jQuery#2.1.1

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and i resolved it pretty easily; I was trying to bower install while running  a server from my machine. I disconnected the server and IDE (webstorm) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i also got the same problem and i tried again all uninstalled everything then after i install again gitbash
command in gitbash

```
$ npm install -g bower   // let it execute
```

once executed

again command

```
$ bower install bootstrap        // let it execute
```

when  executed you got 
if want more then run more commands :)

e.g.

```
$ bower install script.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I encounter this error, what I do is to clean the npm's cache,

```
npm cache clean
```

and if it doesn't work, I uninstall the concerned bower component, and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your old node (it may be < 0.12.0)

And Install node version **> v0.12.0**  (In my case v0.12.7)

Then

```
npm update npm -g
```

And

```
bower install
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by running

`bower cache clean`